Salesforce dataloader #!/bin/bash script errors mentions .zshrc
I'm trying to run a certain application (Salesforce dataloader v61) on MacOS.
The entry point is a bash script:
#!/bin/bash
DL_INSTALL_ROOT="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
source ${DL_INSTALL_ROOT}/util/util.sh

runDataLoader $@

When I run it, it fails seemingly trying to source my .zshrc file:
/Users/achere/dataloader/dataloader_v61.0.0/dataloader_console
/Users/achere/.zshrc: eval: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
/Users/achere/.zshrc: eval: line 26: `  () {'
/Users/achere/.zshrc: line 14: zmodload: command not found
/Users/achere/.zshrc: eval: line 17: unexpected argument `(' to conditional binary operator
/Users/achere/.zshrc: eval: line 17: syntax error near `(['
/Users/achere/.zshrc: eval: line 17: `if [[ $ZSH_VERSION == ([1-4]*) ]]; then'
/Users/achere/.zshrc: line 36: (Ie)__zoxide_hook: syntax error in expression (error token is "__zoxide_hook")

If I comment everything out in my .zshrc it works. How can I run that application without having to do that? I.e., how can I make sure tha a #!/bin/bash script doesn't try to load .zshrc?

wtf, that is horrible software! How about you change the entry point script's interpreter from bash to zsh by replacing /bin/bash in the first linewith the path to zsh?

if you're referring to this util/util.sh then unfortunately it appears to source a bunch of initialization files without regard for the shell

@MarcusMüller I tried that but it caused a Java error later which I didn't get when just commenting out the contents of my .zshrc:
./dataloader_console
Data Loader requires Java JRE 17 or later. Checking if it is installed...
checkJavaVersion:17: condition expected: <
Error: Could not find or load main class com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner

@steeldriver thank you very much for looking into it, so the software explicitly sources .zshrc. I thought it was system-level shenanigans. When I removed zsh-related lines in util.sh, it worked!

"I'm trying to run a certain application (Salesforce dataloader v61) on MacOS." - How are you running it?

The answer courtesy of `@steeldriver.
Turns out, one of the scripts in dataloader imports .zshrc explicitly. The problem was solved by removing the following lines from the util/util.sh script:
    include ${HOME}/.zsh_profile
    include ${HOME}/.zshrc


Less destructively, you could have added something like [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]] || return to the top of your ~/.zshrc
